# Rapidminer: Mapping to boolean column in data base

Tags: postgresql, boolean, rapidminer

I need to convert one text column inside my Rapidminer process pipeline to the boolean data type in order to insert data in a postgres column with a boolean data type. I only can convert text to Nominal, but that doesn't work. I always get a mapping error:"boolean = character varying Hint"

I tried it with "true, false" and "0, 1", but without success.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried to use othe data types than text for the input data.

Comment: There must be a way for such a mapping. I really have tried so many things, without any success.

Comment: What operators have you tried so far?

Comment: I only can convert a text attribute to nominal. Then to binomial. But without access.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be because the text attribute has more than two values.

Comment: So what would be the easiest way to declare such a boolean type. I am extracting a column from csv with two different strings (let us say "ab" and "cd").

Comment: How many different values, including missing values, does the text attribute have before attempting to convert it to a binominal? Missing values will cause silent failure to convert.